# Why does type inference fail for a polymorphic function applied to different inputs withing the same function

Tags: haskell, typechecking

I'm making an interpreter for a subset of C++. The interpreter is written in Haskell.

My `eval` function for expressions returns a new environment, and a value. I encode the values as a new type called `Val`. Minimal example:

```
data Val = I Integer | D Double
```

To evaluate arithmetic expressions, I want to create general function which applies a polymorphic function such as `(+)` or `(*)` to the numbers wrapped inside the `Val` constructors.

I want to have a function like this:

```
-- calculate :: Num a => (a -> a -> a) -> Val -> Val -> Val
calculate f (I i1) (I i2) = I (f i1 i2)
calculate f (D d1) (D d2) = D (f d1 d2)
```

This gives the following error:

```
tmp/example.hs:4:32: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘Integer’
    • In the first argument of ‘D’, namely ‘(f d1 d2)’
      In the expression: D (f d1 d2)
      In an equation for ‘calculate’:
          calculate f (D d1) (D d2) = D (f d1 d2)
  |
4 | calculate f (D d1) (D d2) = D (f d1 d2)
  |                                ^^^^^^^

tmp/example.hs:4:34: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer’ with actual type ‘Double’
    • In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘d1’
      In the first argument of ‘D’, namely ‘(f d1 d2)’
      In the expression: D (f d1 d2)
  |
4 | calculate f (D d1) (D d2) = D (f d1 d2)
  |                                  ^^

tmp/example.hs:4:37: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer’ with actual type ‘Double’
    • In the second argument of ‘f’, namely ‘d2’
      In the first argument of ‘D’, namely ‘(f d1 d2)’
      In the expression: D (f d1 d2)
  |
4 | calculate f (D d1) (D d2) = D (f d1 d2)
  |                                     ^^
```

I can't wrap my head around this. I have two questions:

1. Why does this program fail to type check?
2. How could I implement `calculate` correctly?

I'm only vaguely familiar with universally quantified types, so if that is part of the problem, please explain gently.

Comment: Well the signature suggest that `a` can be *anythong*, but here it is should be or an `Integer`, or a `Double`.

Comment: Willem: Doesn't the signature imply that the function could be any function that takes two inputs of any instance of `Num` and returns a value of the same instance? Like, the type signature of `(+)` is exaclty `Num a => a -> a -> a`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well not every numerical type is an `Integer`, or a `Double`.

Comment: Sure, but could you elaborate on why that would cause the type checking error when the program never calls calculate with anything other that `Integer` or `Double`? I mean, it's not like `map` fails to compile because it accepts a function of type `(a-> b)`, which could be any type. Something else must be going on here, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've correctly identified that you need *universal quantification*. In fact, you already have universal quantification – your signature, like any polymorphic signature, is basically shorthand for

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForall, UnicodeSyntax #-}
calculate :: ∀ a . Num a => (a -> a -> a) -> Val -> Val -> Val
```

meaning: whenever someone wants to use this function, they get to choose some type to put in for `a` upfront. For example, they could pick `Int`, then the function would get specialised to

```
calculate :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Val -> Val -> Val
```

and that's then used at runtime.

But that's no use for you, because you're going to need to use this function for *different* number types. No single specialisation is going to cover all of them.

The solution: delay the choosing of a type. That's accomplished by putting the universal quantor `∀` (you can also write it `forall`) inside the combinator-function part of the signature:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}
calculate :: (∀ a . Num a => a -> a -> a) -> Val -> Val -> Val
```

which will typecheck. It does require the `-XRank2Types` extension because this is a rather more complex beast: now you can't simply picture the polymorphic function as a family of specialisations with concrete monomorphic types, but instead the funtion needs to be ready to instantiate, *at runtime*, the supplied function with whatever types happen to occur in the data structure.

I.e., it needs to pass an additional argument to the function: a “dictionary” containing the `Num` class methods. The underlying implementation GHC generates is something like this:

```
data NumDict a = NumDict {
        addition :: a -> a -> a
      , subtraction :: a -> a -> a
      , multiplication :: a -> a -> a
      , abs :: a -> a
      ...
      }

calculate' :: (∀ a . NumDict a -> a -> a -> a) -> Val -> Val -> Val
calculate' f (I i1) (I i2) = I (f ndict i1 i2)
 where ndict = NumDict ((+) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer)
                       ((-) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer)
                       ...
```

Comment: "the runtime needs to be ready to instantiate the supplied function"... What do you mean by this? Was under the impression that nothing special happened at runtime. Type erasure

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Type erasure happens, but it does not erase typeclass constraints. The first argument of `calculate`, roughly, is a function that takes a dictionary for `Num a` and then two more arguments. The dictionary is chosen and passed at runtime by `calculate`.

Comment: Exactly. I added some explanation to the answer.

Comment: Hmm, I still think the sentence is a little misleading. The dictionaries are manifest in the generated code. The runtime system itself doesn't need to know anything about `RankNTypes` or type classes. It just passes arguments around.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson that was indeed badly phrased. I didn't mean _the runtime needs to do it_ but _it needs to be done at runtime_.